# Android Compose, Anchor the ExposedDropdownMenu to the TextField cursor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

I am creating an sample screen in compose, where i need to show the dropdown with suggesstions while the user is typing without losing the TextField focus.

Desired Output:

[image]

When i have used `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`, dropdown is showing on top of TextField.

```
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTextView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(),
    onTextChanged: ((TextFieldValue) -> Unit) = ::onTextChnaged,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = false
) {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")

    var isDropdownVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = Modifier,
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = it }) {
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                onTextChanged(value)
                value.selection.start
                isDropdownVisible = value.text.isNotEmpty() && value.text.first() == '@'
            },
            label = { Text("Enter your text here.") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            textStyle = textStyle,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            modifier = modifier.menuAnchor(),
        )

        // filter options based on text field value
        val filteringOptions = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }
        if (filteringOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                filteringOptions.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BackHandler(enabled = isDropdownVisible) {
        isDropdownVisible = false
    }


}

fun onTextChnaged(textFieldValue: TextFieldValue): Unit {

}
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a [SearchBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#SearchBar(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.SearchBarColors,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1))
 be better suited here?

Comment: @Leviathan I need a multiline text field, where the dropdown is shown near the cursor.  For SearchBar suggestion will shown below the TextField

Answer (score 0):

In Android Compose, to anchor the `ExposedDropdownMenu` to the `TextField` cursor and show suggestions as a user types, you need to adjust the position of your `ExposedDropdownMenu` so that it appears near the text cursor (caret), and update the filtering logic to respond to text changes. Here's an updated version of your `AutoCompleteTextView` Composable that includes the positioning of the DropdownMenu based on the TextField cursor.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTextView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(),
    onTextChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = true
) {
    var isDropdownVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    var cursorPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        expanded = isDropdownVisible,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = it
            isDropdownVisible = it
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                onTextChanged(value)
                isDropdownVisible = value.text.isNotEmpty()
            },
            singleLine = singleLine,
            textStyle = textStyle,
            label = { Text("Enter your text") },
            modifier = modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                    // Calculate the current cursor position
                    val textLayoutResult = textFieldValue.layoutResult?.value
                    if (textLayoutResult != null) {
                        val cursorRect = textLayoutResult.getCursorRect(textFieldValue.selection.start)
                        cursorPosition = Offset(
                            x = cursorRect.left,
                            y = textFieldSize.height
                        )
                        // Optional: Scroll TextField so the cursor is always visible
                        // coroutineScope.launch { /* Scroll logic */ }
                    }
                },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = isDropdownVisible
                )
            },
        )

        // Calculate dropdown position based on the cursor
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = isDropdownVisible,
            onDismissRequest = { isDropdownVisible = false },
            offset = DpOffset(cursorPosition.x.dp, cursorPosition.y.dp)
        ) {
            options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }.forEach { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = option
                        isDropdownVisible = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = option)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Handle back press
    BackHandler(enabled = isDropdownVisible) {
        isDropdownVisible = false
    }
}
```

Key changes and considerations:

1. A `modifier` has been applied to `TextField` to calculate the global position of the text field and get the size, which is later used to determine the dropdown position.
2. The `onGloballyPositioned` modifier is used to calculate the cursor position within the TextField.
3. The dropdown menu is positioned using `offset` which takes `cursorPosition` to position the dropdown menu relative to the cursor within the `TextField`.
4. You'll want to make sure that the cursor position is updated every time the text changes in such a way that it might affect the cursor's position on the screen. This includes changes to the `TextFieldValue`.

This is a basic implementation and could be further refined based on specific UI and UX requirements. For example, handling screen rotations, complex UI layouts, handling keyboard appearance, etc., would require additional work.